# How to add comma in every strings when it comes from bundle android?

Tags: java, android, string, bundle

I get 4 strings from bundle. But if any one of the string is empty. Comma alone looks which is not looking nice.

So if there is empty string in any one of the 4 strings, I should not add comma.

How to proceed?

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    if (bundle != null) {
     trx1 = bundle.getString("trx1");
        trx2 = bundle.getString("trx2");
        trx3 = bundle.getString("trx3");
        trx4 = bundle.getString("trx4");
     }
```

//String normorTrx = trx1+ ", "+trx2+" ,"+ trx3 + " ,"+trx4;

The above string doesn't work if trx2 is empty or trx3 or trx4 is empty or any combination of two value is empty. 
Where output looks as
 1,,4 or 1,2,,. The above condition normorTrx works only when all 4 datas present. 1,2,3,4 comes from bundle.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: check `if (trx1.isEmpty()) { don't append comma} else { append comma}`

Comment: Use `StringJoiner`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            trx1 = bundle.getString("trx1");
            trx2 = bundle.getString("trx2");
            trx3 = bundle.getString("trx3");
            trx4 = bundle.getString("trx4");
        }


        StringBuilder stringBuilder= new StringBuilder();

        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(trx1)){
            stringBuilder.append(trx1+",");
        }
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(trx2)){
            stringBuilder.append(trx2+",");
        }
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(trx3)){
            stringBuilder.append(trx3+",");
        } if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(trx4)){
            stringBuilder.append(trx4);
        }
       String normorTrx =stringBuilder.toString();
```

Comment: So output should be String normorTrx = stringBuilder?

Comment: but when i use, I get incompatible type

Comment: @Walter use like this `String normorTrx =stringBuilder.toString();`

Comment: Hello i am getting comma, when there is data in trxt1. output: 1,

Comment: exaplain more about this @Walter

Comment: comma should come before and need to remove in trx1. i done.. no issues..

Comment: if you have any idea, kindly let me know for this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49167753/how-to-use-meters-value-in-zoom-level-in-google-maps-android

Answer (score 1):

You can use **StringBuilder** to chieve that:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    if (bundle != null) {
     trx1 = bundle.getString("trx1");
        trx2 = bundle.getString("trx2");
        trx3 = bundle.getString("trx3");
        trx4 = bundle.getString("trx4");
     }


    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            if(trx1 != null && !trx1.isEmpty()){
                sb.append(trx1);
                sb.append(",")
            }

            if(trx2 != null && !trx2.isEmpty()){
                sb.append(trx2);
                sb.append(",")
            }

            if(trx3 != null && !trx3.isEmpty()){
                sb.append(trx3);
                sb.append(",")
            }

            if(trx4 != null && !trx4.isEmpty()){
                sb.append(trx4);
            }

    String normorTrx = sb.toString(); // ----->  your desired result
```

Comment: I receive String normorTrx = sb; incompatible type in this line.

Answer (score 1):

So Simple.
use `StringJoiner`. below is the example.

```
StringJoiner joinNames = new StringJoiner(","); // passing comma(,) as delimiter   
// Adding values to StringJoiner  
joinNames.add("Rahul");  
joinNames.add("Raju");  
joinNames.add("Peter");  
joinNames.add("Raheem");  

System.out.println(joinNames);
```

OutPut:

**Rahul,Raju,Peter,Raheem**

Only for Java 8 and API >= 24