# How to use meters value in zoom level in google maps android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

Previously I used zoom level in google maps by hardcoding. But now it comes from response.

So how to convert the meters by passing into zoom level? In my code, I am displaying a big circle icon and also points. So for both, I use hardcoded zoom level. But now it comes from response.

```
LatLng retailerPosition = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(retailerLatitude), Double.parseDouble(retalerLongitude));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(retailerPosition).title("").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_circle_red)));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
            .newLatLngZoom(retailerPosition, 3)); //3 hardcoded one. 

for (int i = 0; i < listLocation.size(); i++) {
            LatLng sitePosition = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(listLocation.get(i).getRetLatitude()), Double.parseDouble(listLocation.get(i).getRetLongitude()));
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sitePosition).title("").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.round)));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newLatLngZoom(sitePosition, 3)); //3 hardcoded one
        }
```

3 is hardcoded one. But now it comes from response.

"range": "1000" //this comes in response as "meters"

So how to apply this in above logic to convert from meters to zoom level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Please add this Map Utils library:

compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.3'

2. Source code to convert:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. so where should i add this zoomToMeters method?

Comment: mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newLatLngZoom(sitePosition, 3)); //instead of 3, zoomToMeters?

Comment: or no need the above line?

Comment: just  call: zoomToMeters(1000), it will automatically zoom to a corresponding level of 1000 meters

Comment: thanks. Just one doubt. What about this line? mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory .newLatLngZoom(sitePosition, 3))

Comment: mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory .newLatLngZoom(sitePosition, 3)) will zoom at the position: sitePosition to level 3, not meters